# Under what scenarios are the move constructors invoked for constructor arguments?

Tags: c++11, optimization, constructor, move-constructor

I am trying to understand when the move constructors of constructor arguments are invoked.

I will use some examples & scenarios from an actual project below to illustrate my question better.

Some explanation for why I'm seeing the results from these scenarios would be super helpful!

```
//The following code is common to all examples
//This code is the place the object creation begins
std::unique_ptr<AI::Pathfinding::cDirectedWeightedGraph> graph = std::make_unique<AI::Pathfinding::cDirectedWeightedGraph>(std::move(connections));
```

x------------------------------------------------------------x

Scenario 1:

```
//Here is the actual constructor for the class
cDirectedWeightedGraph(std::vector<cConnection> i_connections) : m_connections(i_connections) {}
```

Result:
The move constructor for the std::vector class is invoked.

x------------------------------------------------------------x

Scenario 2:

```
//Here is the actual constructor for the class
cDirectedWeightedGraph(std::vector<cConnection>&& i_connections) : m_connections(i_connections) {}
```

Result:
The move constructor for the std::vector class is NOT invoked.

x------------------------------------------------------------x

Scenario 3:

```
//Here is the actual constructor for the class
cDirectedWeightedGraph(std::vector<cConnection>&& i_connections) : m_connections(std::move(i_connections)) {}
```

Result:
The move constructor for the std::vector class is invoked.

x------------------------------------------------------------x

Scenario 4:

```
//Here is the actual constructor for the class
cDirectedWeightedGraph(std::vector<cConnection> i_connections) : m_connections(std::move(i_connections)) {}
```

Result:
The move constructor for the std::vector class is invoked.

x------------------------------------------------------------x

Observations/Follow Up Questions:

1. It appears to not matter at all if the argument is declared as an rvalue reference.
2. Other than writing a move constructor or move assignment operator for your class, do you ever need to use rvalue references in your constructor?
3. I'm assuming at the location the constructor is invoked, there is no way to invoke the move constructor without passing an rvalue reference (this seems like bad practice either way, I was just curious). I am using std::move() to generate an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

We know that if we call `std::move`, then the move constructor will be called, so 3 and 4 are expected.

For 1, I would first check your compiler settings, debug would not generate a move constructor. If you had a statement there that uses `i_connections`, you wouldn't see the move constructor. clang-tidy even has a rule that detects these cases and suggests to replace 1 with 4.

For scenario 2, the compiler decided not to generate the optimized code. There is probably a heuristic that is working a little bit differently than in case 1. The compiler doesn't have to optimize the code, even if the argument is a `&&`, as it is named and as such requires a call to `std::move` to be moved in all cases.

So for scenarios 1 and 2, it's compiler and flag dependent.

In the end, I would suggest to use 4 as much as possible, as the compiler can optimize the moves if required and the interface is also compatible with copies if required.